# $(window).load doesn't seem to wait for everything to be finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following script:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"-->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).resize(function () { 
           $('body').css('padding-top', parseInt($('#navbar').css("height"))+10);
        });

        $(window).load(function() { 
            alert(parseInt($('#navbar').css("height")));
           $('body').css('padding-top', parseInt($('#navbar').css("height"))+10);         
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
```

Basically I have a fixed top navbar (`<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">`) and it's covering up the top of my page's actual  body content. I came across this solution (after window.load finishes, set the padding of the body based on navbar's height) from many other sources. But it doesn't work. The window.resize works perfectly and will readjust the padding of the body accordingly.

Any idea what's wrong? When I first load the page, the alert statement executes and says the value is NaN. The page behind is still fully white and hasn't loaded at all until I've clicked 'ok'. It's doing this is both chrome and Firefox. Any idea what's happening? Thanks.

Edit:
Adding more code.

This is the body

```
<body ng-app="cosmoApp">
    <div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></div>

    <script src="/scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/cosmo.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is the partial html that Angular shoves into the ng-view div in the body.

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class" jumbotron navbar-brand">
            <h2>Whatever</h2>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/about">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

This is the JS

```
angular.module('cosmoApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', 
function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {templateUrl: "partials/home.html", controller : 'PageCtrl'})
    .when("/services", {templateUrl: "/partials/services.html", controller : "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/gallery", {templateUrl: "/partials/gallery.html", controller : "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/about", {templateUrl: "/partials/about.html", controller : "PageCtrl"})
    .when("/contact", {templateUrl: "/partials/contact.html", controller : "PageCtrl"})
    .otherwise({redirectto: "/"});
}]).controller("PageCtrl", function($scope)
{

});
```

Edit 2:

Adding screenshot of the page load. Why does it think window is loaded at this stage if it's not actually loaded? 
[image]

Comment: Use `$(window).on("load" ...` instead. `$(window).load()` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8. Other than that, make sure `#navbar` exists by `console.log($("#navbar").length)` and obviously make sure it does have a valid height

Comment: @RGraham Yea I tried `$(window).on('load', f())`, `$(window).onload = f..` and `$(window).bind('load', f())`, but they all behave the same.

Is there any alternative approach to ensure the CSS has loaded before re-defining the padding?

Comment: That's not the problem, they still work, they're just deprecated. You should check the other parts of the comment.

Comment: Is `#navbar` added to the DOM asynchronously? Anyway, you have to provide minimalistic sample code in question to replicate issue or at least provide online link where this issue can be checked

Comment: @A. Wolff Just added everything relevant (i think). Does it help? #navbar IS added by Angular...separately...i'm not sure if asynchronous.

Comment: I'm not an angular developper but you should try instead: `$scope.load = function () { alert(parseInt($('#navbar').css("height"))); });` inside your controller. I edited your question to include `angularjs` tag because there is maybe better way and so an angularjs developper could check it

Comment: Instead of `alert(parseInt($('#navbar').css("height")));` test with `alert($('#navbar').length);`. As A.Wolff has stated it is most likely that your navbar element does not yet exist in the page -- and so will alert 0. If you are getting strange results it is always a good idea to test for an element's existence first. The window's load event triggers after all resources have finished loading, it does not wait for other asynchronous code that may have been executed by random libraries you have included on the page. You also have to be aware of other load listeners that may trigger after yours.

Comment: The proper angular approach is to use a directive